# what types of events does cdfinger_input stands for in adb shell getevent

Tags: android, linux, adb

I am using android oreo with Mac OS Mojave.
I was trying to get the input text in the app and then I came across "cdfinger_input" which looks like it has something to do with the text I type on my mobile. I don't know if I am right because I can't find any information about it on the internet.

Here is the what I typed in my adb shell using the terminal and its output.

```
ASUS_X00T_3:/ $ getevent --help                                                                                                  
getevent: invalid option --
Usage: getevent [-t] [-n] [-s switchmask] [-S] [-v [mask]] [-d] [-p] [-i] [-l] [-q] [-c count] [-r] [device]
    -t: show time stamps
    -n: don't print newlines
    -s: print switch states for given bits
    -S: print all switch states
    -v: verbosity mask (errs=1, dev=2, name=4, info=8, vers=16, pos. events=32, props=64)
    -d: show HID descriptor, if available
    -p: show possible events (errs, dev, name, pos. events)
    -i: show all device info and possible events
    -l: label event types and names in plain text
    -q: quiet (clear verbosity mask)
    -c: print given number of events then exit
    -r: print rate events are received
1|ASUS_X00T_3:/ $ getevent -S
add device 1: /dev/input/event9
  name:     "sdm660-snd-card Button Jack"
add device 2: /dev/input/event8
  name:     "sdm660-snd-card Headset Jack"
add device 3: /dev/input/event4
  name:     "SX9310 Cap Touch"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
add device 4: /dev/input/event5
  name:     "stk3x1x-light"
add device 5: /dev/input/event0
  name:     "qpnp_pon"
add device 6: /dev/input/event6
  name:     "stk3x1x-proximity"
add device 7: /dev/input/event3
  name:     "qwerty"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
add device 8: /dev/input/event2
  name:     "cdfinger_input"
add device 9: /dev/input/event7
  name:     "gpio-keys"
add device 10: /dev/input/event1
  name:     "synaptics_dsx"
6400
6400
6400
6400
6400
6400
6400
6400
6400
6400

ASUS_X00T_3:/ $ getevent -il /dev/input/event2
add device 1: /dev/input/event2


bus:      0000
  vendor    0000
  product   0000
  version   0000
  name:     "cdfinger_input"
  location: ""
  id:       ""
  version:  1.0.1
  events:
    KEY (0001): KEY_HOME              KEY_POWER             KEY_MENU              KEY_BACK             
                KEY_CAMERA            0258                  0259                  025a                 
                025b                  025c                  025d                  025e                 
  input props:
    <none>
```

I just want to understand what type of events "cdfinger_input" stands for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cdfinger_input` is just a device name. It does not stand for anything. It's just a string arbitrarily chosen by the device's manufacturer. If I were to guess I'd say that the device in question is a fingerprint sensor.

But instead of guessing you should just use the `getevent -il /dev/input/event2` command to see the actual list of all events supported by the device.

Comment: ASUS_X00T_3:/ $ getevent -il /dev/input/event2
add device 1: /dev/input/event2
  bus:      0000
  vendor    0000
  product   0000
  version   0000
  name:     "cdfinger_input"
  location: ""
  id:       ""
  version:  1.0.1
  events:
    KEY (0001): KEY_HOME              KEY_POWER             KEY_MENU              KEY_BACK             
                KEY_CAMERA            0258                  0259                  025a                 
                025b                  025c                  025d                  025e                 
  input props:

Comment: I tried all the keys and actions but this does not refers to anything using getevent -l. I think it refers to the physical keys. Anyways thanks.

Comment: I just answered your original question - nothing more. You seem to have a problem with comprehending the `getevent -il` output - I suggest you post another question about that issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering.